Does arrow file convert pandas timestamp of datetime64[ns] values with timezone to nanoseconds?
I have a pandas dataframe with a datetime column of the following values:
0   2020-01-01 23:00:57+00:00
1   2021-01-01 23:00:57+00:00
2   2022-01-01 23:00:57+00:00
3   2023-01-01 23:00:57+00:00
4   2024-01-01 23:00:57+00:00

and my arrow table is:
pyarrow.Table
subject: string
timestamp: timestamp[ns, tz=UTC]
col1: string
----
subject: [["s1","s2","s3","s4","s5"]]
timestamp: [[2020-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2021-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2022-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2023-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2024-01-01 18:18:18.000000000]]
col1: [["71264","71264","71264","71264","71264"]]

and my schema is:
subject: string
timestamp: timestamp[ns, tz=UTC]
col1: string
-- schema metadata --
pandas: '{"index_columns": [], "column_indexes": [], "columns": [{"name":' + 565

when I write this dataframe to arrow file using the following command:
import pyarrow as pa
writer = pa.ipc.new_file("/data.arrow", schema)
    writer.write(table)

I use the following approach to read the arrow file in java:
File arrowFile = new File("data.arrow");
FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(arrowFile);
SeekableReadChannel seekableReadChannel = new SeekableReadChannel(fileInputStream.getChannel());
ArrowFileReader arrowFileReader = new ArrowFileReader(seekableReadChannel, new RootAllocator(Integer.MAX_VALUE));

VectorSchemaRoot root  = arrowFileReader.getVectorSchemaRoot(); // get root 
Schema schema = root.getSchema(); // get schema

for (ArrowBlock arrowBlock : ar.getRecordBlocks()) {
    ar.loadRecordBatch(arrowBlock);
    VectorSchemaRoot schemaRoot = ar.getVectorSchemaRoot();

    for (int i = 0; i < schemaRoot.getFieldVectors().size(); i++) {
        FieldVector fieldVector = schemaRoot.getFieldVectors().get(i);); 
// This becomes TimeStampNanoTZVector[1577902698000000000, 1609525098000000000, 1641061098000000000, 1672597098000000000, 1704133098000000000] 
// instead of datetime format
}

I observed above that the values become nanoseconds (long integers) when I read it in Java.
However when the dataframe column only has dates:
2022-01-01
2022-01-02
2022-01-03
2022-01-04

I get the actual datetime formats when I read it.
Is this expected in pyarrow improve the IO efficiency?
UPDATE
To add more information, I am using the following commands to get the schema and table from pandas:
table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
schema = pa.Schema.from_pandas(df)

I drilled down a bit more and I find that the timeZone information is the reason.
If my dataframe has no timezone info
,subject,timestamp,col1
0,s1,2020-01-01 18:18:18,31596
1,s2,2021-01-01 18:18:18,31596
2,s3,2022-01-01 18:18:18,31596
3,s4,2023-01-01 18:18:18,31596
4,s5,2024-01-01 18:18:18,31596

then the table becomes
pyarrow.Table
subject: string
timestamp: timestamp[ns]
col1: string
----
subject: [["s1","s2","s3","s4","s5"]]
timestamp: [[2020-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2021-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2022-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2023-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2024-01-01 18:18:18.000000000]]
col1: [["31596","31596","31596","31596","31596"]]

but if my dataframe has timezone info:
,subject,timestamp,col1
0,s1,2020-01-01 18:18:18+00:00,39355
1,s2,2021-01-01 18:18:18+00:00,39355
2,s3,2022-01-01 18:18:18+00:00,39355
3,s4,2023-01-01 18:18:18+00:00,39355
4,s5,2024-01-01 18:18:18+00:00,39355

then my table becomes:
pyarrow.Table
subject: string
timestamp: timestamp[ns, tz=UTC]
col1: string
----
subject: [["s1","s2","s3","s4","s5"]]
timestamp: [[2020-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2021-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2022-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2023-01-01 18:18:18.000000000,2024-01-01 18:18:18.000000000]]
col1: [["39355","39355","39355","39355","39355"]]


and this timestamp[ns, tz=UTC] will cause the read result in Java to be a long integer as the nanoseconds.

Hey can you update your question with the following details. What is table / schema? How do you read this file in java? and how do you print the list of dates?

@0x26res Updated with the details. I was trying to read the arrow files using python commands but got errors saying: pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Not an Arrow file
with pa.memory_map('/home/qiangyao/Downloads/data.arrow', 'r') as source: ...     loaded_arrays = pa.ipc.open_file(source).read_all()
but this is something separate.

Thanks. I think arrow is working as expected. Timestamp in arrow are represented as  the number of nanos (if you use nano as the unit) since epoch, as an integer 64. I'm not too familiar with the java API, but you may need to convert them your self to a timestamp object (eg an Instant).

@0x26res Yes, that is what I did, check if the ArrowVector is TimeStampNanoVector and if the value is Long then we convert to DateTime myself.
